# Playing same audio on two players simultaneously using just_audio and just_audio_background

Tags: flutter, dart, just-audio

I am working on an app that plays audiobooks, and when you click a book in your list a full window player will start playing the book, however when you close/minimize it, I want a miniplayer to show right about the navbar in the bottom. This player has to continue playing from where the first player "stopped" until the user decides to pause.

Im unsure if this can be achieved without having to have both play the audio at the same time? Reason is that when the Fullscreen is closed, player.Dispose is called.

I currently have a function which saves the position of the player and stores it in shared pref, it however cuts the seconds of, so even if I called that in the miniplayer, it wouldnt continue from the same position.

Im new to flutter/dart btw, with only a few months experience. Thanks in advance

Comment: please make an effort to show your code. a minimum reproducible code that can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Thanks I will do that in the future, as its a company project I wasnt sure what I could share. I will keep this in mind for future posts

Comment: For future reference: its not advisable to post a real code. just formulate a sample code that reproduces the same behavior you are dealing with. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74312836/type-null-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-futurevoid-when-unit-testing-using-mock/74312876#74312876) is a good example of a sample code that can be posted. hope this helps you with future questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a single player and then have two player "widgets" displaying the state of that same player. That way, you don't need to try to stop and start the player - the player can continue playing the whole time while the widgets are the only things changing.

If you're a beginner, the simplest way to define a single player that can be referenced from everywhere is to define it in a global variable, outside of any class declarations (for something more advanced, read about the service locator pattern):

```dart
final player = AudioPlayer();
```

Then let's say you have two widgets to view the state of the same player: `FullPlayerWidget` and `MiniPlayerWidget`. They can both reference the same `player` instance defined above.

Finally, your logic error is that you are calling `dispose` when minimising the full player widget. You shouldn't do that unless you want the audiobook to stop playing permanently. You don't want it to stop permanently, and you don't even want it to stop at all!

Actually, the only thing you want to happen when minimising is a visual thing. You want to hide the full widget and display the mini widget. But on the audio side, you want the `player` itself to be unaffected, continuing to play audio as if nothing had happened. Therefore, in this event you should in fact not call any methods on the `player`.

The best thing you can do as a beginner is to study lots of examples. E.g. [podcastproject](https://github.com/peterscodee/podcastproject) (although its dependencies are a bit out of date now).